# Fuzzification of input values in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, fuzzy-logic

I`m trying to fuzzify input values and get an output by defuzzification on shiny app. But I don't know how to get those values from input.

So is it possible to use input values to fuzzify them and then deffuzify value and make this value as an output? If yes, how? Thanks

Here is just an idea of the code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(sets)
    library(datasets)
    ui <- fluidPage(numericInput(inputId = "one", label="Type number",1, min=1, max=120),
    numericInput(inputId = "two", label="Type number",1, min = 1, max=120),
    numericInput(inputId = "three", label="Type number",1, min = 1, max=120),
    numericInput(inputId = "four", label="Type number",1, min = 1, max=120),
    textOutput("sub"), br(),
    actionButton("button", "Show"),

    br()


    )
    server <- function(input, output){

    variables <- set(wo = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(notMany2 = 15, enough2 = 25, many2 = 35),FUN = fuzzy_cone, radius = 10),
    top = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(notMany3 = 20, enough3 =   50, many3 = 100),FUN = fuzzy_cone, radius = 25),
    c = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(k4 = 52, k3 = 42, k2 = 32,k1 = 22), sd = 3))
    rules <- set (fuzzy_rule(wo %is% notMany2 && top %is% notMany3 
                       || wo %is% notMany2 && top %is% notMany3 
                       || wo %is% notMany2 && top %is% notMany3 
                       , c %is% k1),
    fuzzy_rule( wo %is% notMany2 && top %is% enough3 
                        || wo %is% notMany2 && top %is% many3,c %is% k2))
    system <- fuzzy_system(variables,rules)
    fi <- fuzzy_inference(system, list(wo = 20, top= 10))


    fuz <- gset_defuzzify(fi, 'centroid')

    output$sub <- renderText({fuz})


    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This does not work:                                                     fuzzy_inference(system, list(wo = input$one, top=input$two ));                        fuzzy_inference(system, list(wo = renderText({input$one}), top=renderText({input$two}))).